# Where to ask question about international shipping?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I'm not asking about shipping times, I just need to know what airport(s) an international package from the UK to the US is likely to arrive at.

I guess the closest site for this is Travel.SE, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Doesn't that highly dependent on the carrier? I would assume both DHL and UPS bring international packages first to their own hub where they have both facilities and personnel.

Comment: Why do you care? the package will arrive at your doorstep regardless of the port of the entry... Can you explain more so I can tell you if it will fit in Travel.SE or not..

Comment: @HeidelBerGensis is for a project, we have to find the best possible route of an international package and then compare it to the actual route used.